# Are complementary subspaces necessarily closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I am learning functional analysis by myself and am confused about the definition of complementary subspaces of Banach spaces. In the book I use (Exercise 2.2.1 in "Analysis Now" by Gert Pederson), it seems complementary subspaces are defined to be closed subspaces. I somehow can show that even without closed-ness in the definition, complementary subspaces are closed.

Algebraically, complementary subspaces are the same as they are in the linear algebra
\begin{equation}
 X = X_1 + X_2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
 X_1 \cap X_2 = \phi
\end{equation}
So any vector $x\in X$ has a unique decomposition $x=P_1 x + P_2 x$ with $P_1$ and $P_2=1-P_1$ being the projection operators. Define a new norm $\lVert x \rVert^{'}= \lVert P_1x \rVert + \lVert P_2x \rVert$, one can verify it is a norm and dominates the original norm $\lVert\rVert$. By the open mapping theorem two norms are equivalent and give the same topology. It's clear from the new norm $\lVert\rVert^{'}$ that the projection operators are bounded (continuous). Then the subspaces $X_1 = P_2^{-1}\{0\}, X_2=P_1^{-1}\{0\}$ are closed, being the preimage of a one-point (closed) set.

Comment: "By the open mapping theorem..." it doesn't work like that. The theorem is for Banach spaces.

Comment: Every subspace of a vector space has an algebraic complement. But not every subspace of a normed space must have a complement. Thus algebraic complementary subspaces of normed space aren't necessarily closed. So the assumption is important.

Comment: For example, $c_0$ is not complemented in $\ell^\infty$.

Comment: @Jakobian Thanks for the comment. The space $X$ with the new norm $\lVert\rVert^{'}$ must be Banach for me to use the open mapping theorem. If the subspaces are not closed, this is not guaranteed.

Comment: Yes. Your new normed space is Banach iff the subspaces are closed. So you essentially used what you wanted to prove.

Comment: @Jakobian Exactly, thanks for your explanation and the example.